# In terms of Request.ServerVariables, what does HTTP_REMOTE_USER call from the application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am currently working on an application with a piece of logic that checks for the username, but it appears to be choice of two depending on if the user is generated using the Windows Login system.

```
Dim returnString As String = String.Empty

returnString = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
If returnString Is Nothing Then
 returnString = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REMOTE_USER")
End If
```

I know that LOGIN_USER is the Windows Login name, but where would the HTTP_REMOTE USER come from? Could this possibly be a name stored in a database somewhere? Or Could it be the entered username that is stored via session or cookies whist the user remains logged in? Or am I completely off track and is it neither?

Comment: Here is the complete list with description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx

Comment: Thanks however, HTTP_REMOTE_USER is not on that list, I checked this earlier.

Comment: I think HTTP_REMOTE_USER is not a server variable, or at least it is not available in the server variable list(Request.ServerVariables). I am not sure where are you getting this from.

Comment: It's just what is written in the application, it doesn't cause an error or anything and does return a value so it must be valid, I just can't find where it pulling that value from so I can trace it back